# How to smooth connected polygons without losing their connectivity?

Tags: algorithm, polygon, smoothing, polyline, contour

I have a number of polygons which covers some rectangle.

Each polygons is associated with some type (on the image accessible by link below it's shown by a color).

I need to **smooth polygons and save the topology**.

(i.e. we should to consider the following constraints:

1. The union of the polygons is equal to some rectangle
2. The intersection of any two distinct polygons is empty

(it's definition of the **partition of a set**))

**ADDED**

The egdes shouldn't be straight, on the contrary I need **get smooth edges** of polygons. But edges should remain connected together (i.e. **without gaps and overlaps**)

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stJE9.png)

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: I think I understand the question, but without more information about the representation of the geometry and topology of the rectangle and polygons, any answer I could devise would be just vague hand-waving.

Comment: What are you trying to optimize -- that is, what do you mean by "smooth"?

Comment: Can you show an initial partition and an intended result of smoothing it?

Comment: Also, what are you trying to conserve?  In your example image, all your polygons start out as unions of squares; aside from "topology" (which implies some kind of continuous mapping), is there any other property that you want to conserve?  E.g., should the mapping be differentiable as well?  Should the edges remain straight?  Should area be preserved?

Comment: @comingstorm No, the egdes shouldn't be straight, on the contrary I need get **smooth edges** of polygons. But edges should remain connected together (i.e. **without gaps and overlaps**)

Comment: It's still not clear what you're aiming for.  Do you want curved edges?  (note: if the edges aren't straight, then the regions arguably aren't polygons any more...)  There are a lot more different curves than there are straight edges; you need to decide what *kind* of curves you want.  If you want your curves to be as smooth as possible, then you have to decide:  *what do you mean by smooth?*

Comment: @comingstorm does not matter what kind of smoothing will be used, I just want to get rid of _straight_ edges

Comment: Oh, I see: you want to get rid of the unnecessary corners, which are on the boundary of only 2 regions.  Do you mind turning T-intersections into Y-intersections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a fragment of an answer.

One way to ensure that gaps between polygons don't arise is to devise your data structures such that polygons which have a common edge actually share an edge -- that is your data structures contain one edge which is associated with two polygons.  This would also implement the topological relationship between polygons which share an edge.

I expect that this answer is inadequate, but take the hints you've already been given and clarify your question, explain in more detail what you have and what you want.